# How do I merge two lists into a single list?

Tags: python

I have

```
a = [1, 2]
b = ['a', 'b']
```

I want

```
c = [1, 'a', 2, 'b']
```

Comment: @cdleary's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python/408281#408281 provides performance comparison for various ways of "Flattening a shallow list in python" (flattening `zip(a,b)` gives you the answer).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
[j for i in zip(a,b) for j in i]
```

Comment: [ j for j in i for i in zip(a,b) ] though easier to parse in my head does not work!

Comment: Does read weirdly at first :) Mentally chop off everything up to the first `for` and move it to the end, then read that: `for i in zip(a, b)`, `for j in i`, `j`.

Comment: Neat, but doesn't work if one list is 1 element shorter than the other (still should be able to merge).

Comment: Why not using the concatenation for lists: result = a + b . This is what you can read too!

Comment: @Ralf, It depends on the ordering your require.

Comment: @JohnLaRooy, that is right. Order and duplication were not mentioned ;) If the order plays a role, then I would say, the example with the itertool chain by Mark is nice. BTW, duplication can be avoided through set().

Comment: Amazing, thank you! you saved me after searching for a while.

Answer (score 30):

If the order of the elements much match the order in your example then you can use a combination of [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) and [chain](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#chain):

```
from itertools import chain
c = list(chain(*zip(a,b)))
```

If you don't care about the order of the elements in your result then there's a simpler way:

```
c = a + b
```

Comment: using this in my case: 'c = a+b' -- > lists are not iterable. What then? Only chain works check my question to understand my problem: 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40952892/extract-url-their-names-of-an-html-file-stored-on-disk-and-print-them-respecti'

Comment: for index, row in datas.iterrows():
    textF = re.findall('{{f}}(.*?)}}', row['review'])
    matrixF += textF

    if index==3:
        break

for index in matrixF:
    print index
, it's still works, so it's still iterable i think ? ._.

Comment: There is [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable): `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))` -- perfectly lazy way to do this.

Answer (score 24):

Parsing

```
[item for pair in zip(a, b) for item in pair]
```

in your head is easy enough if you recall that the `for` and `if` clauses are done in order, followed a final append of the result:

```
temp = []
for pair in zip(a, b):
    for item in pair :
        temp.append(item )
```

Comment: I'm normally very comfortable with LEs, but this double looping got me all confused. Thanks for the nice explanation.

Answer (score 5):

An alternate method using index slicing which turns out to be faster and scales better than zip:

```
def slicezip(a, b):
    result = [0]*(len(a)+len(b))
    result[::2] = a
    result[1::2] = b
    return result
```

You'll notice that this only works if `len(a) == len(b)` but putting conditions to emulate zip will not scale with a or b.

For comparison:

```
a = range(100)
b = range(100)

%timeit [j for i in zip(a,b) for j in i]
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.4 µs per loop

%timeit list(chain(*zip(a,b)))
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.9 µs per loop

%timeit slicezip(a,b)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.76 µs per loop
```

Comment: what do you mean by "putting conditions to emulate zip will not scale with a or b"?

Comment: I simply meant that with zip, if one list is longer than the other, the longer list gets truncated to merge it with the shorter list. One could do this by comparing the lengths of each array and then only assigning a shortened version of the longer one. This checking of lengths and truncation does not take any longer if the arrays get bigger.

Comment: Note: This works well for bisecting purposes that favor the first list: it tolerates being the same length or one longer than the second `slicezip([1,2,3],[4,5])`, which means you don't have to handle uneven lists in that case (which is very nice)

Answer (score 4):

If you care about order:

```
#import operator
import itertools
a = [1,2]
b = ['a','b']
#c = list(reduce(operator.add,zip(a,b))) # slow.
c = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(a,b))) # better.
```

`print c` gives `[1, 'a', 2, 'b']`

Answer (score 3):

*Simple.. please follow this pattern.*

```
x = [1 , 2 , 3]
y = ["a" , "b" , "c"]

z =list(zip(x,y))
print(z)
```

Comment: That won't give me a flat list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():

drinks = ["Johnnie Walker", "Jose Cuervo", "Jim Beam", "Jack Daniels,"]
booze = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
num_drinks = []
x = 0
for i in booze:

    if x < len(drinks):

        num_drinks.append(drinks[x])
        num_drinks.append(booze[x])

        x += 1

    else:

        print(num_drinks)

return
```

main()

Comment: Please you have to explan your answer.

Comment: Did you come up with this answer after 5 rounds?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a standard / self-explaining solution, i hope someone will find it useful:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
b = ['1', '2', '3']

c = []
for x, y in zip(a, b):
    c.append(x)
    c.append(y)

print (c)
```

output:

```
['a', '1', 'b', '2', 'c', '3']
```

Of course, you can change it and do manipulations on the values if needed

Answer (score -3):

```
c = []
c.extend(a)
c.extend(b)
```

Comment: The desired result is entirely different.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: if it answers the question and is different from all other answers, why not support it? i believe there's not much context to the quesetion so any relevant answers are welcome.