# Interleaving Lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:
`[a, b, c] [d, e, f]`
I want: 
`[a, d, b, e, c, f]`

What's a simple way to do this in Python?

Comment: In that specific order?  Or just appended to each other?  Your resulting list is out of order.  If you need them in that order, what is the rule that defines that order?

Comment: @dusan: Not at all a dup of that question.

Comment: Wait, why isn't it a duplicate?

Comment: @eboix: No, this is not about simply concatenating the lists, but about interleaving them.

Comment: @eboix: Look at the order of the elements in the merged list.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I see the pattern now.  Silly me...

Comment: Oh, yeah. I didn't see that it was not alphabetical order.

Comment: The key is to recognize that interleaving is almost the same as zipping, except that you need the flatten the result. The answers by Sven Marnach and F.J below show two ways of doing that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471999/how-do-i-merge-two-lists-into-a-single-list

Comment: @SvenMarnach Sorry! I misread the result list.

Comment: why not using `list_one.extend(list_two)`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One option is to use a combination of `chain.from_iterable()` and `zip()`:

```
# Python 3:
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list_a, list_b)))

# Python 2:
from itertools import chain, izip
list(chain.from_iterable(izip(list_a, list_b)))
```

**Edit**: As pointed out by sr2222 in the comments, this does not work
well if the lists have different lengths.  In that case, depending on
the desired semantics, you might want to use the (far more general) `roundrobin()`
function from the [recipe
section](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) of the
`itertools` documentation:

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Comment: +1. Probably the best solution. But it might be worth explaining why this works: zipping gives [(a, d), (b, e), (c, f)], and then chaining flattens that into [a, d, b, e, c, f]. (Encouraging people to learn itertools is always a good thing.)

Comment: Is this going to play nice if the lists are not of equal, or at least +/-1, length?

Comment: @sr2222: Good point – it will stop on the shorter list.

Comment: @sr2222: depends what you mean by "nice". If you try it on [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and [6, 7, 8] you'll get back [1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8]. That's certainly _a_ reasonable answer, but it may not be the one that fits your use case. (And without knowing your use case, it's hard for anyone to say more than that.)

Comment: @abarnert Of course it's dependent on use case, just wanted to point it out for people of the future reading this answer.  :)

Comment: This is an alternate implementation of roundrobin (I guess) that I made to anwer @sr2222's comment, before Sven posted his update: `list(ifilter(lambda x: x != None, chain.from_iterable(izip_longest(a, b))))`

Comment: @lazyr: Careful with using `None` as a sentinel – it might also occur in one of the lists.  You can create a unique sentinel that compares unequal to everything else by `sentinel = object()`.

Comment: `cannot import name 'izip'` with python 3.x, but [`zip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32659581/3719101) works fine :)

Comment: @iago-lito Yup, this answer was for Python 2 – updated now.

Answer (score 35):

Here is a pretty straightforward method using a  list comprehension:

```
>>> lists = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
>>> [x for t in zip(*lists) for x in t]
['a', 'd', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'f']
```

Or if you had the lists as separate variables (as in other answers):

```
[x for t in zip(list_a, list_b) for x in t]
```

Comment: +1, but as with Sven Marnach's answer, it might be worth explaining why it works: zip the lists, then flatten the result. Because it's not intuitive to most new users that "[x for t in l for x in t]" means "flatten l".

Comment: Maybe just my preference, but this answer seems slightly less complex to me.

Answer (score 4):

This one works only in python 2.x, but will work for lists of different lengths:

```
[y for x in map(None,lis_a,lis_b) for y in x]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something simple using built in functions:

```
sum(zip(list_a, list_b),())
```

Comment: `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`

Comment: This isn't the best way of joining multiple lists.  It has O(n²) complexity and should be avoided.

Comment: See [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) for further information.

Comment: @Makoto, Type error has been fixed.

Comment: Fair enough.  You may have to edit it one more time since my vote is locked.  Also, if I wanted it back as an original list, I'd have to wrap it with a `list()` call.

Comment: @sblom: No, `n` is `len(list_a)` in this case.  -1

Comment: @SvenMarnach, absolutely not. If there are 95 items in the first list, they are _not_ going to get copied 95 times (times/plus some constant), they're each going to get copied *exactly once* when `sum` creates the list from encountering `list_b`. That's not O(N^2), that O(N). I agree that it's O(N^2) on *number of sublists*, but it is _not_ O(N^2) on length of either of the sublists.

Comment: @sblom: You would be concatenating 95 pairs if the lists have 95 items.  And this would mean the growing tuple would be copied in each step.  This *is* O(n²) with n being the length of the input lists (assuming they have the same length).  You can simply do some timings to confirm this.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, Oh, right--sorry. I accidentally shifted my argument to the scenario from the link you included earlier (and was actually even playing with timings just to make sure I was right) and lost sight of the scenario currently under discussion. Don't I feel silly.

Comment: @sblom: Never mind, I do this kind of mistake regularly. :)  As a final comment, if n would be two, the preferred way of concatenating of course is `a + b`, not `sum((a, b), [])`.  There is *never* a reason to use this anti-pattern.