# How to add two list up in alternate positions? - python

Tags: python, list, concatenation

How to add two list up in alternate positions?

E.g. I have:

```
>>> x = [1,3,5,7,9]
>>> y = [2,4,6,8,10]
```

and when i add the list up, i get:

```
>>> x + y
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

but the desired output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I have tried this but **is there other way to achieve the desired output?**

```
>>> z = []
>>> for i,j in zip(x,y):
...     z.append(i)
...     z.append(j)
... 
>>> z
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: @200OK this question is not exactly the duplicate of the question you've linked.

Comment: It is actually, and there are several others too: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Interleaving+Lists+in+Python

Comment: =) this one is more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125212/interleaving-lists-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> x = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> [b for a in zip(x, y) for b in a]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

`zip(x, y)` is used to pair up the items in `x` and `y`:

```
>>> x = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> y = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
>>> list(zip(x, y))
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
>>>
```

If you are using Python 2.x though, you may want to replace it with [`itertools.izip(x, y)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) so that you do not create a list unnecessarily.

Comment: `list(chain(*zip(x,y)))`

Comment: @iCodez Try with: `list(merge(y, x))`

Comment: @200OK - Darn.  I forgot it did that. :)  I'm going to remove that part so nobody gets confused.