# Using BeautifulSoup4 to get string with/without <p> tag inside <div> section

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a legacy webpage to scrap using BS4. One of the section is a long essay that I need to scrap off. That essay is formatted strangely like this:

```
<div id='essay'>
  this is paragraph1
  <p>this is paragraph2</p>
  this is paragraph3
  <p>this is paragraph4</p>
</div>
```

Using bs4, I tried the following:
Using

```
soup.find('div', id='essay').text
```

I can extract

```
'this is paragraph1' and 'this is paragraph3'
```

OR

```
ps = soup.find('div', id='essay').find_all('p')
for p in ps:
    print p.text
```

I can extract

```
'this is paragraph2' and 'this is paragraph4'
```

If I use both, I will get paragraph 1, 3, 2, 4, which is out of order. I need to make sure the paragraph sequence is also correct. What can I do to achieve that?

EDIT: The problem in the question is only an example, it does not guarantee to interleave between even and odd number of paragraphs... Let me clarify my question a bit: I want to have a way to extract the paragraph IN SEQUENCE regardless of having < p > or not.

Comment: `soup.find('div', id="essay").text` gets exactly what you want so there must be more to your actual html. That or you are using some old buggy version of bs4

Answer (score -1):

BeautfulSoup4 also has recursive mode, which is enabled by default.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<div id='essay'>
  this is paragraph1
  <p>this is paragraph2</p>
  this is paragraph3
  <p>this is paragraph4</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
r = soup.find('div', id="essay", recursive=True).text
print (r)
```

Works perfectly for me.
Try to update BeautifulSoup4 using pip.

Comment: The default is `recursive=True`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, I've edited that.

Comment: My point is that `soup.find('div', id="essay").text`  works and is the same as `soup.find('div', id="essay", recursive=True).text`   but the OP already stated that it did not  for them

Comment: OP should then post his full HTML, and update bs4 using pip...

Answer (score -2):

If the lists are the same length it might be easier to interleave them, instead of writing code to get around the original formatting with Beautiful Soup

```
from itertools import chain

list_a = ['this is paragraph1', 'this is paragraph3']
list_b = ['this is paragraph2', 'this is paragraph4']

print(list(chain.from_iterable(zip(list_a, list_b))))


# ['this is paragraph1', 'this is paragraph2', 'this is paragraph3', 'this is paragraph4']
```

More info here: [Interleaving Lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125212/interleaving-lists-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth answer, please check out my edit, I added some newer information to the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I totally missed that question! Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

The following seems to work

```
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup("""
<div id='essay'>
this is paragraph1
<p>this is paragraph2</p>
this is paragraph3
<p>this is paragraph4</p>
</div>
""", "lxml")

main = soup.find('div', id='essay')
for child in main.children:
    print(child.string)
```

Comment: You have to specify your parser in the function BeautifulSoup. Otherwise you may get unwanted behaviours in other systems, and a big warning.