# Breadth-first version of itertools.chain()

Tags: python, python-itertools

In `itertools` there's `chain`, which combines multiple generators in a single one, and in essence does a depth-first iteration over them, i.e., `chain.from_iterable(['ABC', '123'])` yields A, B, C, 1, 2, 3. But, there's no breadth-first version, or am I missing something? There's of course `izip_longest`, but for large numbers of generators this feels awkward, as the tuples will be very long and possibly very sparse.

I came up with the following:

```
def chain_bfs(*generators):
    generators = list(generators)
    while generators:
        g = generators.pop(0)
        try:
            yield g.next()
        except StopIteration:
            pass
        else:
            generators.append(g)
```

It feels a bit verbose to me, is there a more Pythonic approach I'm missing? And would this function be a good candidate for inclusion in `itertools`?

Comment: So you basically want to chain the output of `zip()` here? I'd not call that breath-first vs. depth-first (that implies a deeper tree).

Comment: I want the resulting generator to output A, 1, B, 2, C, 3 for the given example. And, if supplied with 'AB' and '1234', then A, 1, B, 2, 3, 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I merge two lists into a single list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471999/how-do-i-merge-two-lists-into-a-single-list)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`collections.deque()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) to rotate through your iterators; rotating a deque is much more efficient. I'd also call it a chained zip, not a 'breath first chain', as such:

```
from collections import deque

def chained_zip(*iterables):
    iterables = deque(map(iter, iterables))
    while iterables:
        try:
            yield next(iterables[0])
        except StopIteration:
            iterables.popleft()
        else:
            iterables.rotate(-1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(chained_zip('ABC', '123'))
['A', '1', 'B', '2', 'C', '3']
>>> list(chained_zip('AB', '1234'))
['A', '1', 'B', '2', '3', '4']
```

There is also a [`roundrobin()` recipe in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) that does the same, using the [`itertools.cycle()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

```
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).__next__ for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Comment: Heh, personally this is clearer than [`roundrobin` from the recipies section of the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). Good good.

Comment: @Veedrac: ah, I knew there was a itertools recipe for this too, thanks for reminding me about its name. :-)

Comment: Ah, I missed the recipes section. This seems to solve it rather elegantly :) Not sure which version I prefer, the first one is a bit more readable, although the clever use of __next__ also appeals to me.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you'd still consider this too "verbose"...

```
def chain_bfs2(*generators):
    generators = map(iter, generators)
    while generators:
        for i, generator in enumerate(generators):
            try:
                yield generator.next()
            except StopIteration:
                del generators[i]

print list(chain_bfs2('AB', '123'))  # ['A', '1', 'B', '2', '3']
```