# Algorithm to return a reordered range for data rendering

Tags: python, algorithm, rendering

Here are examples:

```
given: 1,2,3   [list or range of numbers]
return: 2,1,3  [reordered list]

given: 1,2,3,4,5
return: 3 1 5 2 4 

given: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
return: 4 1 7 2 6 3 5 OR 4 7 1 5 3 2 6 or similar

given: 1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9
return: 5,1,9,3,7,2,8,4,6 or similar
```

In rendering you start with the center, then the most extreme cases, and become more and more detailed. This is NOT random. I'm in python, but theres got to be a name for this in comp sci. Help appreciated.

#### Edit to add

even case -

```
given: 1234 
return: 2,1,4,3 OR 3,1,4,2 OR 2,4,1,3 OR 3,4,1,2
```

Comment: After the extreme cases, does it work from the bounds to the middle? I think you have to specify more the expected behavior since with this question there are different possible solutions each user can/cannot accept according to their taste. (opinion-based answers are usually not accepted).

Comment: After the initial extreme cases, the "next extreme cases after the initial ones" seem to be used in the examples he posted. For instance, in the third example, 4 is the center, 1 and 7 are the initial min and max, followed by 2 and 6, and 3 and 5 afterwards.

Comment: What happens when there are an even number of inputs?

Comment: even case - given: 1234 -  2,1,4,3 OR 3,1,4,2 OR 2,4,1,3 OR 3,4,1,2

Comment: So you want it give you the middle, ends, then bisect each half for the rest of the values? sounds like a recursive function to me.

Comment: You should include that sort of information *as an edit to the original question*. But that's gross. The case for evens has a pretty straightforward linear time solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid, although ungraceful solution:

```
def sigorder(lst):
    result = []
    l = len(lst)
    if l <= 2:
        return lst
    if l > 2:
        result.append(lst[l/2])
        result.append(lst[0])
        result.append(lst[-1])
        right = sigord(lst[l/2+1:-1])
        left = sigord(lst[1:l/2])
        result.extend(slicezip(left, right))

    return result
```

Inner, recursive function:

```
def sigord(lst):
    result = []
    if len(lst) < 3:
        return lst
    else:
        l = len(lst)
        result.append(lst[l/2])
        left = sigord(lst[0:l/2])
        right = sigord(lst[l/2 + 1:len(lst)])
    result.extend(slicezip(left, right))
    return result
```

[slicezip()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26013222/3579910) (Note: conveniently handles the potential unevenness of the left/right lists automagically)

```
def slicezip(a, b):
    result = [0]*(len(a)+len(b))
    result[::2] = a
    result[1::2] = b
    return result
```

Outputs for lists length 4-9 :

```
[3, 1, 4, 2]
[3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
[4, 1, 6, 2, 5, 3]
[4, 1, 7, 2, 5, 3, 6]
[5, 1, 8, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4]
[5, 1, 9, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 8]
```

Comment: this is exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
def extreme_cases(upd_itrr, new_itrr):
    new_itrr.append(min(upd_itrr))
    new_itrr.append(max(upd_itrr))
    upd_itrr.remove(min(upd_itrr))
    upd_itrr.remove(max(upd_itrr))
    if len(upd_itrr) >= 2:
        extreme_cases(upd_itrr, new_itrr)
    return upd_itrr, new_itrr


def reordered_range(itr):
    new_itr = []
    center = 0
    if len(itr) % 2 != 0:
        center = itr[len(itr) // 2]
    elif len(itr) % 2 == 0:
        center = itr[(len(itr) // 2) - 1]
    new_itr.append(center)
    upd_itr = itr[:]
    upd_itr.remove(center)
    upd_itr, new_itr = extreme_cases(upd_itr, new_itr)
    if upd_itr:
        new_itr.append(upd_itr[0])
    return new_itr


print(reordered_range([1, 2, 3]))
print(reordered_range([1, 2, 3, 4]))
print(reordered_range([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(reordered_range([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
print(reordered_range([1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
[3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
[4, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 5]
[5, 1, 9, 2, 8, 4, 7, 6]
```

Comment: So this is on the right track, but I think you see why its not exactly what I'm after. The term 'recursive bisection' sounds on point to me, but im still curious if there are tools out there that do this? Maybe writing it is just the easiest way haha.

Comment: Your code starts with center, then extremes and works from the extremes to the center. I'm interested in the center, then extremes, then bisecting all gaps until all terms in the original list have been used.

Comment: this is still close. i think the last two ranges you printed don't properly bisect after the third term. taking an attempt at it myself

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify what exactly you are looking for? Is the fourth example you posted (1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9) correct? With it returning 5,1,9,3,7,2,8,4,6?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
import numpy as np
from copy import copy

def bisecting_order(lst):

    # bisecting order of an unordered list
    result = []
    l = len(lst)
    if l < 3:
        return lst
    result.append(closest(lst,np.mean(lst)))
    result.append(min(lst))
    result.append(max(lst))

    # get bisections
    while len(result)!=len(lst):
        temp_list = copy(result)
        temp_list.sort()
        for i in xrange(len(temp_list)-1):
            newnum = closest(lst,np.mean([temp_list[i],temp_list[i+1]]))
            if newnum in result:
                continue
            else:
                result.append(newnum)
    return result

def closest(mylist,mynum):
    return min(mylist, key=lambda x:abs(x-mynum))
```