# What is the best way to merge 2 byte arrays?

Tags: python

Let's suppose i have 2 bigs arrays (i have put smaller arrays in this example):

```
a1=bytes([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
a2=bytes([11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81])
```

What i want to do is to merge this 2 arrays this way:

```
[10,20 , 11,21 , 30,40 , 31,41 , ...
```

What i want is to take 2 bytes from first array, then 2 from second array, etc.

Here is what i done. It works but i think there is a best way to do this, without having to create intermediates arrays:

```
a3 = bytearray()
for i in range(0, len(a1), 2):
    a3.append(a1[i])
    a3.append(a1[i+1])
    a3.append(b1[i])
    a3.append(b1[i+1])

output_array=bytes(a3)  # Very important: i need bytes() object at the end
```

Comment: Please be aware the answer you selected makes a copy on every slice.

Comment: For lists of 10000 numbers wim's answer is 100x times faster than Dekel's (50.3 µs vs 4.28 ms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chunk taken from here: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)
Merge taken from here: [How do I merge two lists into a single list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471999/how-do-i-merge-two-lists-into-a-single-list)

Combined into this:

```
def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

a1 = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]
b1 = [11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81]
combined = [j for i in zip(chunks(a1, 2),chunks(b1, 2)) for j in i]
out = bytes(bytearray([x for pair in combined for x in pair]))
==> b'\n\x14\x0b\x15\x1e(\x1f)2<3=FPGQ'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with slice assignment:

```
a1 = bytes([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
a2 = bytes([11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81])

n = len(a1)

a3 = bytearray(2*n)
a3[0::4] = a1[0::2]
a3[1::4] = a1[1::2]
a3[2::4] = a2[0::2]
a3[3::4] = a2[1::2]
a3 = bytes(a3)
```

Output:

```
>>> a3
b'\n\x14\x0b\x15\x1e(\x1f)2<3=FPGQ'
>>> list(a3)
[10, 20, 11, 21, 30, 40, 31, 41, 50, 60, 51, 61, 70, 80, 71, 81]
```

---

*Edit:* Here is a method without intermediate copies

```
def gen(a1, a2):
    i1 = iter(a1)
    i2 = iter(a2)
    while True:
        for it in i1, i1, i2, i2:
            try:
                yield next(it)
            except StopIteration:
                return

a3 = bytes(gen(a1, a2))
```

Comment: do you think i can do less copies ? In the last line, does it make a copy ?

Comment: Yes the last line makes a copy.  I will try to think of a way to do it without that last copy....

Comment: Turns out your first solution (with the slices) is way faster than the second one

Comment: Yeah, I'm not surprised.  It uses heavily optimized parts of CPython.  But speed is not the only possible reason to try and avoid copies (there can be also memory limitations warranting it).

Answer (score 0):

This is another option:

```
a1=bytes([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
a2=bytes([11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81])

merged = bytes((a1 if (i&3)<2 else a2)[i-(i&2)-2*(i>>2)]
               for i in range(2*len(a1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

using slice assignments on the bytes directly

```
a1 = bytes([10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80])
a2 = bytes([11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81])
a3 = bytes()

for i in range(int(len(a1)/2)):
    a3 += a1[i*2:i*2+2] + a2[i*2:i*2+2]
# a3 = b'\n\x14\x0b\x15\x1e(\x1f)2<3=FPGQ'
```

Comment: I think each a3+= opération will create and copy into a new bytes() object?